# Append single package folder to sys.path

Tags: python

I use a script under virtualenv, that requires bzrlib package which is not available in my virtualenv but is included in my system python packages: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/`

If I want to use it, one option is to extend sys.path, but I would have to include the parent folder `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which contains many other packages, that I don't want to make available. Is there any easy way to include just `bzrlib` package?

Comment: What about creating a link in different directory and importing using that? Or even in your own project.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I just did that, thanks for confirming same idea. I thought that there is maybe some tweak that would allow me to extend sys.path as explained.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks for you suggestion. I'll go with symlink to avoid changing import statements in initial script/package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a link in different directory and importing using that? Or even in your own project.

```
ln -s /package/dir/path /project/dir/path
```

If you have to load it remotely, here is the link provided by @unutbu showing how to do it:

[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```